# Java: Increment by 2 the two inputted integer

Tags: java, increment

Can someone help me please.. just starting java..:(
How can I display all possible values based on the given minimum input value, maximum input value and the incrementing value?

for example:
min value: 1
max value: 10
increment value: 2

the result will be:  1, 3, 5, 7, 9

this is what i got so far..

```
public class DisplayIncrement {
public static void main(String []args){

    int min, max, increment;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
    in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
    in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
    in.nextInt();

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=10; i+=2){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Store the value of min and max and use those in loop.

Comment: Assign the values you read using the Scanner to variables (for example, "min", "max" and "step") and use these variables in your for loop. for(i = min; i <= max; i+= step)

Comment: Can someone tell me how this question got negative score? It is well formulated, he gives an example of what he wants and he posts a very small and clean SSCCE with his progress so far... +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Notes:

1- `in.nextInt();` reads an integer from the user, blocks until the user enters an integer into the console and presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The result integer has to be saved in order to use it later on, and to do so save it into a variable, something like this:

```
int value = in.nextInt();
```

In your code, you need to assign the 3 integers that the user enters to the corresponding variables:

```
System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
min = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
max = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
increment = in.nextInt();
```

2- You are implementing the loop very well, but you just need to use the user's inputs rather than using explicit integers:

```
for(int i = min; i <= max; i += increment)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.out.println("Enter min value: "); 
 int minVal =  in.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter max value: "); 
   int maxVal =  in.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Enter increment value: "); 
 int increment = in.nextInt(); 

for(i=minVal; i<=maxVal; i+=incremement){ 
    System.out.println(i); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you declared the integers needed, however, you did not actually use them.

So, when you are calling the method `in.nextInt();`, you are actually "getting" an integer. So you can set the integers min, max, and increment to that method respectably. like this,

```
 System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
min = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
   max = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
  increment =  in.nextInt();
```

So for the complete answer, something like this should work.

```
public class DisplayIncrement {
public static void main(String []args){

    int min, max, increment;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
   min = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
   max = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
  increment =  in.nextInt();


    for(int i=min; i<=max; i+=increment){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class DisplayIncrement {
public static void main(String []args){

int min, max, increment;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
int min=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
int max=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
int inc=in.nextInt();

int i;
for(i=min; i<max; i+=inc){
    System.out.println(i);
}
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaws in your code are obvious but...

```
public class DisplayIncrement {
   public static void main(String []args) {

   int min, max, increment;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
   min = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
   max = in.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
   increment = in.nextInt();

   for(int i = min; i <= max; i += increment)
      System.out.println(i);
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class DisplayIncrement {

public static void main(String []args){

int min, max, increment;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
  min =  in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
 max =   in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
 increment =  in.nextInt();

for(; min<=max; min+=increment ){
System.out.println(min);
}
}   

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []args){

int min, max, increment;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
int minval=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
int maxval=in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
int incr=in.nextInt();

int i;
for(i=minval; i<=maxval;i+=incr){
System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to close the Scanner at the end.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DisplayIncrement{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int min, max, increment;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter min value: ");
    min = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max value: ");
    max = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter increment value: ");
    increment = in.nextInt();

  //for(initial value; condition; increment/decrement)
    for(int i=min; i <=max; i+= increment){
    System.out.println(i);
    }
        in.close();
}

}
```